# jQuery tabs - opening pagination links inside a tab

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I'm having the following setup of jQuery UI tabs:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            type:'post',
            async: false,
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab." );
            }
        },
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
                $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });     
});
```

this loads tabs ok:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="div-s.php">Summary</a></li>
          <li><a href="content.php?div=Production">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="content.php?div=Digital">Recordings</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

my fist tab `div-s.php` contains pagination. I expect for pagination links to be opened in the same tab, yet when I click on them, browser actually redirects me to `div-s.php?pagenum=2`

how can i fix this please?

Comment: is this really complicated? may be i just took wrong approach?..

Comment: paste your code inside the tab... the code inside your tabs will not work as tabs.. I mean, the `tab` plugin will setup tabs for `a` in `li`'s in your `div#tabs` but the content loaded for each tab will work as 'simple HTML'. So, if you have a link, like yout pagination link, it will works as a normal link

Comment: ok i'll try that tomorrow... but wouldn't it make my index page overloaded?

Comment: in fact... your link inside tab content will not reload your tab (your tab is not an iframe)... the tab plugin will "turn off" your links for the tabs with the function set in `load` attribute of plugin

Comment: @Rafael Verger this worked! thanks - post your answer i will accept it and put 100 points to you...

Comment: @Rafael Verger the only thing - how can i still have hash in address bar so it can be bookmarked or referenced thru link? and i don't want such links - http://localhost/isrc/index.php?pagenum=26 where you can see pagination... just http://localhost/isrc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happening: the jquery.tab plugin "turn off" your tab links when  you enable the `ajaxOptions` in the attributes map.

So, when you click in some tab, the content will be loaded by AJAX requests and inserted in tab panel. All the HTML elements in your tab content will work as ordinary elements if you do not add event listener or any kind of script to them. Then, when you load the content that has your paginations links and you click in one of them, you will be doing a click in a normal link that you reload all the page, since your tab panel is not an inframe.

**The solution:**

The function that you set in `load` attribute is doing nothing, but it will work to force ajax load in links inside tab panel with a little modification :)

```
$(".ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content").delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content').load(this.href);
});
```

Finished :) Execute this function after run the tab plugin and all link element inside `.ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content` will force their own tab to reload with their own href